# PHPCrawl: Output sitemap to XML file on server

Tags: php, xml-parsing, sitemap, web-crawler, phpcrawl

I am trying to use PHPCrawl for my website's sitemap. However, I am having trouble trying to get it to output to an xml sitemap, on the server. Any help?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done or tried so far?

Comment: I have only tried, $report = $crawler->getProcessReport(); - as my PHP knowledge for this specifically is not too inclined.

Comment: Have you used the [example script](http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/example.html) as the basis for implementing it? Any output/errors would be useful at this point by turning on error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Hi, yes I am using the example.php script...they happen to leave out the part I am looking for (outputting to a file) if you look near lines 31 / 32 ish...they just put a comment regarding it.

Comment: Anybody? Really coud use help getting PHPCrawl to output an xml sitemap / written to the server/ FTP.

Answer (score 1):

In the official phpcrawl-forum you can find a example script for doing this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpcrawl/forums/forum/307696/topic/6037903